# Why doesn't disable attribute work on Bootstrap-select?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, icheck, bootstrap-select

I want to style my website forms, inputs and selects. I used [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for the inputs and [**Bootstrap-select**](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) for selects and [**iCheck**](http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/) for checkboxes. The problem is that iCheck does not work correctly with Bootstrap-select.

Here is jsFiddle test: http://jsfiddle.net/36Xpf/

Now, try to check the iCheck checkbox, the select of bootstrap-select will not be disabled. Then check the standard square checkbox, the select of bootstrap will be disabled.

I get the attribute disalbled to select if a checkbox is checked usign jQuery `.change()`:

```
$('#checkbox1').change(function(){
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.selectpicker').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('.selectpicker').attr('disabled', true);
  }                   
});
```

What did I do wrong? Why the disabled attribute doesn't work on bootstrap select?
Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a plugin, not a regular checkbox, you have to listen for events that it actually supports :

```
$('#checkbox1').on('ifChanged', function(){
    $('.selectpicker').attr('disabled', this.checked).selectpicker('refresh');
}).iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-red',
    radioClass: 'iradio_flat-red' 
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/36Xpf/1/)

Comment: @charlietfl - thanks, that's cool, I've never used selectpicker, I always just create my own dropdowns. Have never used iCheck either, but reading the docs all the events and how to handle them seems to be well documented.

Comment: @adeno have never seen either of them either...just saw the `refresh` method and made sense that directly changing property of original select would need a refresh

Comment: @charlietfl - Added it to the answer, listening for the correct event seems to disable the dropdown, but the refresh method also changes it's style to look like it's disabled, so good catch.

Comment: I just finally figured out easiest way to do checkbox or radio with no script. Look at css for these...no script used on page  http://topcoat.io/topcoat/#checkbox  Creative use of `:after`

Comment: @charlietfl - topcoat I've seen before, and it looks good, but the blue outline on focus kept me from using it on a recent project, and Bootstrap was selected instead.

Comment: right...not about the actual style, but the css rules to modify check box visuals without needing script impressed me

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('input#checkbox1').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-red',
    radioClass: 'iradio_flat-red' 
});
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();


$(document).on('ifChecked','#checkbox1',function(){
      $('.selectpicker').prop('disabled',true);
     $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
});
$(document).on('ifUnchecked','#checkbox1',function(){
     $('.selectpicker').prop('disabled',false);
     $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
});


/*standard checkbox*/
$('#checkbox2').change(function(){
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.standard').attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.standard').attr('disabled', false);
  }                   
});
```

use this js code